# The navigation reducer is not called while navigating

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to achive the nested navigation using [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) I have a reducer as following below :

```
import AppNavigation from '../Navigation/AppNavigation'

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const newState = AppNavigation.router.getStateForAction(action, state) 
  console.log("reducer is running")     
  return nextState || state;
}
```

From one of the screen I am trying to navigate to another screen using

> this.props.navigation.navigate('OrderPreviewAssigned')

I can see the dispatch action in my console but the reducer is not getting triggered.

**console output :**
[image]

PS : The reason I am trying to achieve because **I want to Prevent navigating twice when clicking a button quickly** , So my plan is to read the current route and if the route is different than only navigate or don't.

Comment: On Button click, disable the button. That will prevent the second click from doing anything.

Comment: Where are you calling the reducer?

Comment: @VamshiGudipati reducer is called withni the combineReducers. reducer is called sometime.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I can disable it, but the buttons are in the list view so it unnecessary to track all. any other options

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not set up the redux integration correctly with React Navigation. You need to pass state and dispatch to the main AppNavigator like so:

```
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(AppRouteConfigs);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
        state: this.props.nav,
      })} />
    );
  }
}
```

See the Redux integration docs from React Navigation for more info and a working example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux

Comment: Already I have done this. But still it's not working. I am using the ignite boilerplate and it's done there.